# Pdf.dart package implement fontFallback to print emojis

Tags: flutter, dart, pdf-generation

I tried without success many solutions proposed on the net
I am trying to print texts (stored in a local database) which include emojis (smatphone origin) and special french caracters (ie Œ )
I can't solve the problem of "Future" when embedding a fontFallback...
My code :

```
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';

static Future emoji() async =\> await PdfGoogleFonts.notoColorEmoji();

static pw.Widget cell(pw.Context context, int index) {
String texte = SQLHelper.listeItemsRepas()\[index\];

    // Text including some emojis
    
    
    // Create a custom TextStyle with fallback fonts
    pw.TextStyle(
      fontFallback: emoji(),
    );
    return pw.Container(
      constraints: const pw.BoxConstraints.tightFor(
          width: double.infinity, height: 22.0),
      padding: const pw.EdgeInsets.all(3),
      child: pw.Text(
        texte,
        style: const pw.TextStyle(
            fontSize: 9),
        textAlign: pw.TextAlign.left,
        softWrap: true,
        maxLines: 6,
    
        //  style: style,
      ),
    );

}

    // Text including some emojis
```

Can you give me the correct code ?

Comment: Did you find any possible solution? I'm in the same situation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I placed instructions inside the PageTheme as follows (hope it's understable)

```
Future<pw.PageTheme> myPageTheme(PdfPageFormat format) async {

final icons = await rootBundle.load("assets/Materialicons.ttf");
final noto = await rootBundle.load("assets/NotoColorEmoji-emojicompat.ttf");
final alumni = await rootBundle.load("assets/AlumniSans-Regular.ttf");

  final iconsTtf = pw.Font.ttf(icons);
  return pw.PageTheme(
    pageFormat: PdfPageFormat.a4,
    orientation:pw.PageOrientation.portrait,
    margin: const pw.EdgeInsets.only(
        top: 50.0,
        bottom: 40.0,
        left: 55.0,
        right: 55.0
        ),
    theme: pw.ThemeData.withFont(
      base:   pw.Font.ttf(alumni),
      icons: iconsTtf,
      fontFallback: [pw.Font.ttf(noto)]
    ),
  );
}
```

and it worked.
@JavierGarcia:Let me know if it's not clear.

Answer (score 0):

Flutter Doctor:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.13.6, on macOS 14.0 23A344 darwin-arm64, locale en-MX)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 15.0)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2022.2)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.82.2)
[✓] Connected device (4 available)
[✓] Network resources
```

Part of my code as an example ->

```
pdf.addPage(
pw.MultiPage(
  theme: pw.ThemeData.withFont(
    base: await PdfGoogleFonts.quicksandRegular(),
    bold: await PdfGoogleFonts.quicksandMedium(),
    icons: await PdfGoogleFonts.notoColorEmoji(),
    fontFallback: [await PdfGoogleFonts.notoColorEmoji()],
  ),
  pageFormat: PdfPageFormat.a4,
  build: (pw.Context page_context) => [
```